# Returning data for service to controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, return, return-value

I need to retrieve output data from a service by providing a input date. data is executed on service but I am unable to return output data to controller. I made a plunker  for code.link is 
 Plaunker Link

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4Uho7njMAXryTDOfwcLP?p=preview

Comment: cant add with question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` your `$http.get` and inside `.then` your final modified variable, say `obj`.

Like this:

```
return $http({
    url: 'miqaat.json',
    method: 'GET',
})
.then(function(response) {

    var all_miqaats = response.data.response;
    var obj = all_miqaats.find(function(v) {
        return v.miqaat_date == dat
    });

    if (obj == undefined || obj == "") {
        console.log("obj = ");
        console.log(obj);
        obj.isHoliday = "100";
        //  return obj;
    } else {
        obj.mq_title = obj.title;
        obj.isHoliday = "101";
        // return obj;
        console.log("Data from Service");
        console.log(obj);
    }

    return obj;
})
```

And, since this returns promise, in controller you need to change it to:

```
getMiqaat.findMiqaat($scope.date).then(function(res) {
  $scope.miqaat = res;
});
```

*Whether you should move your `.then` and `catch` to `controller` or not should depend on how much you `reuse` that code. So, wouldn't comment on that until I know the details.*

[**working demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Th71mvUcykgt92WQUO5H?p=preview)

Comment: @R.Sharma glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of catching the promise from the factory. Catch it from the controller. only return the http inside the factory.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, getMiqaat) {
    $scope.date = "2017-04-11";
    getMiqaat.findMiqaat($scope.date)
        .then(function(response) {
            var all_miqaats = response.data.response;
            var obj = all_miqaats.find(function(v) {
                return v.miqaat_date == $scope.date
            });
            if (obj == undefined || obj == "") {
                console.log("obj = ");
                console.log(obj);
                obj.isHoliday = "100";
                $scope.miqaat = obj;
            } else {
                obj.mq_title = obj.title;
                obj.isHoliday = "101";
                $scope.miqaat = obj;
                console.log("Data from Service");
                console.log(obj);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
            response.response = "Internal Server Error!";
        });;
});
app.factory('getMiqaat', function($http) {
    return {
        findMiqaat: function(date) {
            var dat = date;
            console.log(dat);
            return $http({
                url: 'miqaat.json',
                method: 'GET',
            })
        }
    };
})
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tNMmzRtMK4ccCWZrZRHh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

By using below mention code it will be working fine. Please make sure keys are matching as per your json.

Controller Code :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, getMiqaat){
   $scope.date = "2017-04-11";
   console.log("date ::"+$scope.date);
   $scope.status;
   $scope.miqaat;
   getMiqaatData();
   function getMiqaatData() {
       getMiqaat.findMiqaat($scope.date)
           .then(function (response) {
               $scope.miqaat = response.data.response[0];
           }, function (error) {
               $scope.status = 'Unable to load  data: ' + error.message;
           });
   }

});

app.service('getMiqaat', function($http){

            this.findMiqaat = function(date){
                var dat = date;
                console.log(dat);
               return  $http({
                   url: 'miqaat.json',
                   method: 'GET',
                });
              }

})

Json :

{
  "status":true,
  "message":"List of the miqaats",
  "response":[
    {"miqaat_date":"2017-04-11",
      "mq_title":" New Year",
      "isHoliday" :"101"
    },
    {"miqaat_date":"2017-04-09",
      "mq_title":"Some Fest",
      "isHoliday" :"101"
    }
    ]
}
```